# PHP based in-website mailing system

Tags: php, system, mailing

I know this question is rather vague, but how do I proceed about creating a php based in  website mailing system in a community website?  Any input would be appreciated. I don't know how to start.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I would start with the basics

1. Just learn how to send an email - nothing special just send the mail (http://phpmailer.worxware.com/)
2. Then add a form to communicate with your script (http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp)
3. Then maybe add some validation (http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp)
4. Then protect it with something like CAPTCHA (http://recaptcha.net/)

Once you have all this, you can start playing around with HTML email (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_e-mail) and allowing your users to have more control over what gets emmedded in the email.

The best advice I can give is to start small and not get too fancy too quickly.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to figure out how to send email PHP, there are endless options. The most basic is using PHP's built - in mail function (http://php.net/mail). More seriously, you can use PHPMailer: http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/ If you're looking for an out of the box solution, you can use PHPList: http://www.phplist.com/

If I misundestood and you're looking at handing out email addresses on your website, you can look into Google Apps: http://www.google.com/apps/

I'm not sure where else to point you.

Comment: I am not looking for sending emails through PHP, but rather ... code a system where users can message themselves in the website.

Comment: if that's what you're looking for, the answer is, just start programming it. Use PHP and MySQL to store the messages. Not sure what you're really looking for.

Comment: Actually, that is what I will end up doing, except I will have to add spam blocks, giving the users the ability to block. etc. 

It would be good if there is an open source code out there that I can use.

Answer (score 0):

1. Know the mail limits of your mail
   server that php will be using, this
   could severely limit your mailing
   list growth.
2. Use some sort of database to store list member
   emails.
3. When you are ready to send
   mail just use the php `mail`
   function to send your message (can
   put all the addresses in bcc, or
   send out a single message to each
   user.

Comment: I don't know why someone modded you down - this seems like good advice to me given how vague the question is.

Comment: Vague questions call for general answers...

Comment: I am sorry, I can't mod it up(don't have enough reputation). Thanks for answering. I had no clue where to start. Sorry again for the vague question.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a website Private Messaging system (PM) rather than email? Like many forums use?

If so it's probably too big a question to answer here, I've found this http://sourceforge.net/projects/privatemessagin/ on sourceforge which might give you a head-start. But as a programming project even for a relative beginner it shouldn't be too difficult.

Are your users already sign in with a username and password?  If so that's half the problem solved, now all you need is some way to send a message, which should be just a simple form that posts to a database, then when a user logs in he needs to be alerted that they have a mail which is just a case of querying the database. Nothing too complicated.